# Como melhorar a performance de uma busca por chave?

Tags: delphi, desempenho, delphi-xe8, dicionário

Tendo em vista que `TDictionary` expõe apenas maneiras de recuperar valor através da chave, tenho o seguinte algorítimo para buscar uma chave a partir de seu valor:

```
var
    Table: TDictionary<Int64, Extended>;

function KeyOf(Value: Extended): Int64; inline;
var
    Key: Int64;
begin
    Result := -1;
    if not Table.ContainsValue(Value) then
        Exit;
    for Key in Table.Keys do
        if Table.Items[Key] = Value then
        begin
            Result := Key;
            Exit;
        end;
end;
```

- Estou chamando esta função em um *loop* que executa pelo menos umas 50 mil vezes.
- Preciso manter a indexação por inteiros que não se repetem.
- Durante a execução a estrutura vai comportar em média 50 items.
- Seria também válido substituir esta estrutura por qualquer outra.

E então a minha questão: existe uma maneira de realizar a mesma tarefa com melhor desempenho quanto à velocidade de execução?

Answer (score 1):

**Atualizado 26/06/2016**

Guill, você pode utilizar um `TPair` para percorrer e encontrar o valor que precisa de forma mais eficiente.

```
function KeyOf(Value: Extended): Int64; inline;
var
  vIterator: TPair<Int64, Extended>;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if not Table.ContainsValue(Value) then
    Exit;

  for vIterator in Table do
  begin
    if vIterator.Value = Value then
    begin
      Result := vIterator.Key;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Você pode efetuar o teste com seus registros e verificar se acontece uma melhora na busca.

---

**Dê uma lida neste link também, contém uma explicação mais detalhada**: [Delphi TDictionary iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26100018/5263999)

Comment: Não seria `TPair`?

Comment: Tem razão, editei a resposta com a correção, obrigado

Comment: Porém não houve uma melhora significativa. Embora tenha tornado possivelmente mais rápido.

Comment: No caso do `TDictionary` creio que a melhor opção de busca seria essa. Me fala o propósito do seu uso com o `TDictionary`, talvez a gente possa considerar outras estruturas mais flexíveis.

Comment: É um uso bem específico. Tenho um _array_ de objetos. A `Table` deve conter entradas que associem um valor `Extended` ao índice de certos objetos contidos no _array_ mencionado. A utilidade do algoritmo é verificar se já há um objeto associado ao valor correspondente. Só deve ser possível uma entrada de cada objeto e uma entrada de cada valor distinto.